# Why does this Java rendering use a nested do-while loop?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I've been learning how to make 2D games in Java from a tutorial, and can't figure out why the render uses a do-while loop inside of a do-while loop, shown here:

```
do {
    do {
        Graphics g = null;
        try {
            g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            render(g);
        } finally {
            if (g != null) {
                g.dispose();
            }
        }
    } while (bs.contentsRestored());
    bs.show();
} while (bs.contentsLost());
```

I understand the rest of the stuff in the method, I just can't figure out why it uses a do-while loop for the contentsLost with a do-while loop for the contentsRestored inside.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be ripped straight from the [`BufferStrategy` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html).

Basically, this makes sure that the last attempt to use `getDrawGraphics` produced a viable output, as they are typically backed by a `VolatileImage` which can be reclaimed by the system at any time.

Have a read of [`BufferStrategy#contentsRestored`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html#contentsRestored%28%29), [`BufferStrategy#contentsLost`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html#contentsLost%28%29), [`VolatileImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

If `contentsRestored` is `true`, then whatever you drew to the `Graphics` context has been discard and needs to be redrawn.  The intention is to ensure that only a fully realised image is pushed to the hardware via `BufferStrategy#show`

If `contentsLost` is `true` the `VolitileImage` which is backing the `BufferStrategy` has been lost and needs to be re-constructed and re-shown.

Answer (score 0):

That code is taken from the `BufferStrategy` in [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as an example of double buffer rendering

Documentation says that:

```
contentsLost() : Returns whether the drawing buffer was 
                    lost since the last call to getDrawGraphics.
contentsRestored(): Returns whether the drawing 
                    buffer was recently restored from a 
                    lost state and reinitialized to the 
                    default background color (white).
```

So, I think the loops are for make sure that all the graphic works is lost because the content is restored.